# CASE WHEN 2 conditions Questions

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 2 tables.

- 1st Table: Dates (i.e 22-10,2017)
- 2nd Table: mm-dd (col 1) and Y/N flag (col 2).

I want to write something like this:

```
CASE 
    WHEN (FORMAT_DATETIME('%m-%d', a.Date) = monthDate.monthDate 
          AND monthDate.currentWeekFlag = "Y" 
        THEN "Y" 
        ELSE "N" 
END AS WFC
```

But I get an error:

> Syntax error: Parenthesized expression cannot be parsed as an expression, struct constructor, or subquery

How can I fix this?

I tried an `IF` statement, `CASE` statement but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You have extra ( in your query:

Check this out:

```
select 
CASE 
    WHEN FORMAT_DATETIME('%m-%d', a_date) = b_month_date 
          AND current_week_flag = "Y" 
        THEN "Y" 
        ELSE "N" 
END AS WFC
from 
(select current_date() as a_date, '11-01' as b_month_date, 'Y' as current_week_flag)
```